# How to format postCSS files with .css extension in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I'm using `WebStorm version 2017.2.4` and I use postCSS syntax in files with `.css` extension. Is there any way to make WebStorm format code in these files like in files with `.pcss` extension?

Edit:

Code fomatting when `postCSS dialect` is set:

```
@import "../../../helpers/_helpers.css";

.block {
  padding: $ step_4;

  &__title {
    font-size: $ font_size_6;
    margin-bottom: $ step_4;
  }
}
```

But it should be:

```
@import "../../../helpers/_helpers.css";

.block {
  padding: $step_4;

  &__title {
    font-size: $font_size_6;
    margin-bottom: $step_4;
  }
}
```

How it looks in ide:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried setting up CSS Dialect? Should help as per my knowledge.

Comment: @LazyOne formatting breaks on variables

Comment: Please provide sample code: the source (correct format) and what you are getting after reformatting (bad format). The source must be as plain text (so it can be copy-pasted).

Comment: My IDE (PhpStorm 2017.2.4 with PostCSS plugin) complains on `$step_4` and other variables even in `.pcss` file. From what I see such syntax is not yet supported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24368 ; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26383

Comment: @LazyOne that's sad. thank you.

Comment: 1) How does it look there on your computer? Does it show errors/warning for them (variables) or not? Would be good to see some screenshots. 2) Vote/comment those tickets -- more votes the higher the chance to see it implemented soon (as is "why work on something that no one shows no interest for")

Comment: @LazyOne added screenshot

Comment: Thanks. IDE shows errors in `.pcss` file .. which means it does not understand those variables. So for me it's rather expected that it may not format them correctly. Definitely vote/comment those tickets if you wish to have such syntax supported in this IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Install the PostCSS plugin, and then go to `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Stylesheets | Dialects`, and make sure to set **Project CSS Dialect** to `PostCSS`

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/dialects.html

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with the warnings about @extend for postcss-extend-rule.